# How to fix the Blogger template?

Tags: blogger

My site is http://www.techrone.com (Blogger), I'm very new to the blogging (a month experience). I'm not worry about the income, all I want is to build the backlinks to my blog.

The problem I'm facing with the template is when I upload the new template to the Blogger, in the homepage it's showing 5 posts (fine), but in the second page it's only showing 2 posts. Same problem with the other templates also and I'm losing some of the posts (not showing total posts i.e., 35).

I can't able to put other scripts (infolinks) also in the template (present one).

Please help me anyone, I will provide you my login credentials also.

This is the problem I'm facing with the template:

[img link](http://www.techrone.com/p/blog-page_22.html)

Comment: Your "img link" is 404.

Answer (score 0):

You already have 5 posts in second page and if you want to change then replace any number in "max-results=5" tag under blogger template > HTML...